# Converting a character vector to time and extracting values

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

Hi I am having some trouble with date-time objects in R. I have a column that is actually just a time column but when it’s bought into R it’s read as a character vector but with a random date as well. My initial thought approaching this problem was to first convert that time column to a datetime object using `lubridate::mdy_hms()` and then extracting just the time using `strftime()` or `srtptime()` but my understanding is that `strptime()` only applies to character vectors whereas `strftime()` applies to PosiXct values. I use the `mdy_hms()` function to convert the field to a PosiXct object and then try to extract only the time using `strftime()` but it doesn’t really work. I get this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

I tried this again but using the `hms` package, however it does not recognize the full values in my time vector and will convert everything to `NA` values. This is why I thought to first convert all of the values in that character vector as date-time values and then "throwing away" the date value as it is incorrect. This is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

OM <- read_csv('OM_sightings-1948-2019.csv', na = c("", "NA", "<Null>")) %>%
    #Rename the ID column to OM_ID --> indicates that this entry came from OM database
    rename(OM_ID = ID, Time = Time1, OM_Source = Source) %>% 
    # Drop the Time2, column
    select(-Time2) %>% 
    # Convert 0.0 to NA in both the ActLat and ActLong columns
    mutate_at(vars(ActLat, ActLong), na_if, y = 0)

#Fix the date and time objects in the db
OM_time <- OM %>% 
    mutate(Time = as_hms(Time),
           SightDate = as.Date(mdy_hms(SightDate), tz = "US/Pacific"),
           SightDateTime = mdy_hms(paste(SightDate, Time1), tz = "US/Pacific"))
```

It runs fine, and I can see my "mutated" df, however I get these warning messages that I understand (mostly) but unsure of how to troubleshoot:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Time`.
ℹ Lossy cast from <character> to <hms> at position(s) 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, ... (and 102131 more)
ℹ Input `Time` is `as_hms(Time)`. 
2: Lossy cast from <character> to <hms> at position(s) 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, ... (and 102131 more) 
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `SightDateTime`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
ℹ Input `SightDateTime` is `mdy_hm(SightDate, tz = "US/Pacific") + Time`. 
4: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

This is a sample  subset of my data:

```
structure(list(OM_ID = c(94079, 75473, 95592, 50725, 24689, 73538, 
10246, 107438, 10129, 74301, 107371, 63757, 43427, 93087, 16374, 
28869, 38644, 42348, 89933, 83809, 53855, 96622, 52702, 28263, 
991), SightDate = c("4/22/2015 0:00:00", "7/15/2011 0:00:00", 
"6/30/2015 0:00:00", "6/26/2007 0:00:00", "8/12/2000 0:00:00", 
"6/11/2011 0:00:00", "6/28/1990 0:00:00", "12/7/2018 0:00:00", 
"6/20/1990 0:00:00", "6/26/2011 0:00:00", "12/5/2018 0:00:00", 
"9/1/2009 0:00:00", "8/27/2005 0:00:00", "11/14/2014 0:00:00", 
"6/11/1997 0:00:00", "9/10/2001 0:00:00", "9/8/2004 0:00:00", 
"7/18/2005 0:00:00", "6/25/2014 0:00:00", "8/6/2012 0:00:00", 
"5/16/2008 0:00:00", "7/25/2015 0:00:00", "9/10/2007 0:00:00", 
"8/16/2001 0:00:00", "1/6/1977 0:00:00"), Time = c("12/30/1899 14:00:00", 
"12/30/1899 15:00:00", "12/30/1899 19:21:00", "12/30/1899 9:30:00", 
"12/30/1899 9:30:00", "12/30/1899 12:00:00", "12/30/1899 18:30:00", 
"12/30/1899 13:00:00", "12/30/1899 18:00:00", "12/30/1899 11:52:00", 
"12/30/1899 9:15:00", "12/30/1899 15:33:00", "12/30/1899 9:00:00", 
"12/30/1899 13:48:00", "12/30/1899 15:00:00", "12/30/1899 5:45:00", 
NA, "12/30/1899 16:15:00", "12/30/1899 12:30:00", NA, "12/30/1899 12:00:00", 
"12/30/1899 13:00:00", "12/30/1899 12:30:00", "12/30/1899 8:45:00", 
"12/30/1899 14:15:00"), Month = c(4, 7, 6, 6, 8, 6, 6, 12, 6, 
6, 12, 9, 8, 11, 6, 9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9, 8, 1), Day = c(22, 
15, 30, 26, 12, 11, 28, 7, 20, 26, 5, 1, 27, 14, 11, 10, 8, 18, 
25, 6, 16, 25, 10, 16, 6), Year = c(2015, 2011, 2015, 2007, 2000, 
2011, 1990, 2018, 1990, 2011, 2018, 2009, 2005, 2014, 1997, 2001, 
2004, 2005, 2014, 2012, 2008, 2015, 2007, 2001, 1977), Pod = c("Orcas", 
"JpLp", "JK", "Orcas", "L", "J", "Orcas", "J", "J", "JK", "J", 
"L12s", "Orcas", "J", "Orcas", "Orcas", "JKL", "J", "J", "J", 
"J", "JKL", "JL", "JL", "Orcas"), LikelyPod = c("Ts", "JKLp", 
"JpKp", NA, NA, "JL53", NA, NA, NA, "JpKp", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SRs"), Direction = c(NA, 
"mill", NA, NA, "E", "SE", "N", "N", "W", NA, "N", "NW", "N", 
NA, "N", NA, "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "SW", NA, "N", "N"), FishArea = c("17C", 
"7", "7", "7", "19C", "7", "7", "9", "18C", "18C", "11", "7", 
"7", "9", "7", "7", "7", "18C", "7", "7", "18C", "18", "29", 
"7", "10"), Quadrant = c(89, 184, 181, 184, 257, 181, 185, 397, 
151, 152, 420, 185, 181, 387, 169, 181, 181, 162, 176, 170, 163, 
151, 80, 176, 413), Lat = c(48.96, 48.46, 48.5, 48.46, 48.31, 
48.5, 48.44, 47.9, 48.76, 48.74, 47.33, 48.44, 48.5, 48.12, 48.62, 
48.5, 48.5, 48.74, 48.56, 48.65, 48.71, 48.76, 49.01, 48.56, 
47.55), Long = c(-123.73, -123.1, -123.17, -123.1, -123.36, -123.17, 
-123.03, -122.46, -123.02, -123.08, -122.44, -123.03, -123.17, 
-122.71, -123.17, -123.17, -123.17, -123.3, -123.21, -123.24, 
-123.26, -123.02, -123.16, -123.21, -122.41), UTMx = c(446800, 
492000, 487000, 492000, 473400, 487000, 497400, 539100, 497800, 
493500, 540300, 497400, 487000, 520500, 486900, 487000, 487000, 
477600, 484200, 482300, 480700, 497800, 488100, 484200, 542200
), UTMy = c(5423900, 5367800, 5372600, 5367800, 5351700, 5372600, 
5365800, 5305200, 5401200, 5399200, 5242800, 5365800, 5372600, 
5329700, 5386000, 5372600, 5372600, 5399000, 5378600, 5389300, 
5395300, 5401200, 5428700, 5378600, 5266600), OM_Source = c("TWM-SA-Pub", 
"TWM-SW", "TWM-HYD-Rel", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-SW", 
"TWM-SA-Rel", "TWM-SA-Rel", "TWM-SA-Rel", "SPOT", "TWM-SA-Pub", 
"SPOT", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-HYD-Rel", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-SA-Pub", 
"TWM-SA-Rel", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-SW", "BCCSN", "TWM-SW", "Soundwatch", 
"BCCSN", "TWM-Pager", "TWM-SA-Rel"), ActLat = c(NA, 48.452, NA, 
NA, NA, 48.488, NA, NA, NA, 48.7667, NA, 48.4585, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 48.5385, 48.682, 48.738, 48.7876, 49.0108, NA, NA
), ActLong = c(NA, -123.0777, NA, NA, NA, -123.1233, NA, NA, 
NA, -123.0776, NA, -123.065, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -123.1725, 
-123.251, -123.253, -123.0389, -123.1659, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I appreciate any help! I’m fairly new/self-taught and I’m having a hard time understanding the best way to work with time data in general.

Comment: This comes down to what the times represent. If they are times of day, you would be best storing them as date-times and only printing the time part. If they are durations, you can choose to either store them as integer numbers of seconds or minutes, or use something like `duration` from lubridate.

Comment: You've shared your data after some of the processing you discussed, and with the "tz" column.  It might be more helpful to post example data from a step earlier in the process, before converting the time at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that! I just updated the ```dput()``` of my subset. Please let me know if that works okay!

Comment: @AllanCameron sorry for not being clear, I am trying to store these data as a time of day object. Not a duration. Honestly, I'm really annoyed with how this data was imported because in the original DB there is no date attached in the time column and I think this is an artificat of export and import across different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Dates and times can be pretty tricky in R, since there are so many different ways it can be represented.  `lubridate` doesn't have a class that is just time, but the related package `hms` adds a time class that can make it easier.

I often find it helpful to have both Date and Date/Time columns so you can use the part that makes the most sense.
With the example data, using lubridate::mdy_hms(SighDate) it converts to a date at midnight.  `hms::as_hms(Time)` worked for me.  Then add the two to create at date_time column, then convert the Date to a date class if you need it for analysis.  Below I created a new column for time, to track what it's doing, but would tend to replace the time column.

```
library(lubridate)
library(hms)
library(tidyverse)
# OM = your data provided above 

OM2 <- OM %>%
      mutate(SightDate = mdy_hms(SightDate, tz = "America/Los_Angeles"),
             Time2 = as_hms(mdy_hms(Time)),
             Date_time = SightDate+Time2,
             SightDate = as.Date(SightDate)
             )

OM2 %>%
      select(OM_ID, SightDate, Time, Time2, Date_time, everything())

# # A tibble: 25 x 20
# OM_ID SightDate  Time  Time2 Date_time           Month   Day  Year Pod   LikelyPod Direction FishArea Quadrant   Lat
# <dbl> <date>     <chr> <tim> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#       1  94079 2015-04-22 12/3~ 14:00 2015-04-22 14:00:00     4    22  2015 Orcas Ts        NA        17C            89  49.0
# 2  75473 2011-07-15 12/3~ 15:00 2011-07-15 15:00:00     7    15  2011 JpLp  JKLp      mill      7             184  48.5
# 3  95592 2015-06-30 12/3~ 19:21 2015-06-30 19:21:00     6    30  2015 JK    JpKp      NA        7             181  48.5
# 4  50725 2007-06-26 12/3~ 09:30 2007-06-26 09:30:00     6    26  2007 Orcas NA        NA        7             184  48.5
# 5  24689 2000-08-12 12/3~ 09:30 2000-08-12 09:30:00     8    12  2000 L     NA        E         19C           257  48.3
# 6  73538 2011-06-11 12/3~ 12:00 2011-06-11 12:00:00     6    11  2011 J     JL53      SE        7             181  48.5
# 7  10246 1990-06-28 12/3~ 18:30 1990-06-28 18:30:00     6    28  1990 Orcas NA        N         7             185  48.4
# 8 107438 2018-12-07 12/3~ 13:00 2018-12-07 13:00:00    12     7  2018 J     NA        N         9             397  47.9
# 9  10129 1990-06-20 12/3~ 18:00 1990-06-20 18:00:00     6    20  1990 J     NA        W         18C           151  48.8
# 10  74301 2011-06-26 12/3~ 11:52 2011-06-26 11:52:00     6    26  2011 JK    JpKp      NA        18C           152  48.7
# # ... with 15 more rows, and 6 more variables: Long <dbl>, UTMx <dbl>, UTMy <dbl>, OM_Source <chr>, ActLat <dbl>,
# #   ActLong <dbl>
```

I'm pretty sure Access represents dates and times as numeric values representing the amount of time since some origin.  It looks like the origin used is 12/30/1899, which shows up in your Time column.  You could also look to your settings when you export from Access to csv.  I'm more familiar with excel, but would think they set it up similar so you can manipulate the format before importing.

Comment: Thank you! So yes, I didn't want to give too much detail for fear of making my post confusing, but yes. I have a Date column with the true date and the time column (in Access) only displays a time in 24 hour format. However, when imported into R it attaches a random date. Using the ```hms::as_hms``` call does what I feared and drops all of the contents of the Time vector and instead populates it with NA values. I'll update my OP to reflect a better question, code, and sample data. Thank you so much fo your help!

Comment: I updated with the new sample data.  Using the sample you provided as_hms worked fine, but if it's returning NA's it might be caused by something outside of the subset you posted.

Comment: I think your errors are coming from using as_hms on data that has a date component as well as a time component.  You can either first convert to POSIXct with mdy_hms(), or strip out the meaningless date component before converting character to time.

Comment: Yes! That worked Thank you! However, when I have ```NA``` time values, they are still populated to the SightDateTime column i.e (1/1/2010 NA) but I was hoping if there was NA for time it wouldn't be appended to SightDateTime. I also still get a "tz" column added onto the end of my df whereas that hasn't happened in the past and I'm not sure why? The is the code I ended up running: 
```OM_time <- OM %>% 
    mutate(Time = as_hms(mdy_hms(Time)),
           SightDate = as.Date(mdy_hms(SightDate), tz = "US/Pacific"),
           SightDateTime = paste(SightDate, Time), tz = "US/Pacific")```

Comment: You are creating the tz column in the code above,I think it should be inside the parentheses for mdy_hms.

Comment: You have to deal with the NA's in the time column separately. Something like replacing NA with noon or midnight after you've parsed the time, and before combining with date